# React Native how to change scrollview zIndex on android

Tags: react-native, scrollview, z-index, android-scrollview

I'm making a table, left fixed, right scrolling, click on row to expand/fold the action button, the button crosses the scrollView from the left, I set the zIndex of scrollView to -1, but the button cannot be clicked in the area above the ScrollView, it will become row click. I have tried to change the left zIndex/elevation to no avail

[code like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJxj7.jpg)

[code](https://snack.expo.io/wk77RBBWS)

I have been troubled for a long time. Please help me,thanks

Comment: The only picture is not enough to help you. Update your post and insert a piece of code, please.

Comment: Can someone help me? emergency